# gotoAndStop MovieClip outside of extended MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, function, actionscript

I have a Inventory system that worked on the timeline.  Now, I am trying to connect it to a class but I'm having difficulties.

On my stage, i have a `MovieClip` with the instance name `InventoryMc`
Inside `InventoryMc`, I have 15 more `MovieClips` with the instance name `itemSlot1`, `itemSlot2` etc...  The `gotoAndStop` functions are not working properly...
I have no document class, just classes that extend the `MovieClips`...

This is my `BeginnerChest` class, when clicked it calls a function from the `Inventory` class:

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class BeginnerChest extends MovieClip {

    private var _inventory:Inventory;


    public function BeginnerChest() {
        _inventory = new Inventory();
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, begClick);
        claimBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _inventory.claimClick);
    }


    public function begClick(e: MouseEvent) {
        play();
    } //ends startBtnClick;


    public function insertText(str) {
        return str + "\r"
    }
}
}
```

This is my `Inventory` class...  I took out other functions that I didn't think were necessary.  I am trying to get this `addToslot` function to work, but it never seems to find the frame `Hammer` or whatever it is.  Yes, I do have it labeled inside of the `itemSlots` MovieClip.

```
package {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Inventory extends MovieClip{


    var Slot1: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot2: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot3: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot4: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot5: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot6: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot7: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot8: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot9: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot10: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot11: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot12: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot13: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot14: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var Slot15: Array = ["empty", "empty", 0]; //[ItemId, Display Name, Sell Price]
    var slotClicked: String;
    var NewItem = "None";
    var BoxesReset: Boolean = false;
    var InventoryFull: Boolean = false;
    var ItemSelected = "";
    var ItemUse = "None";
    var CurrentSlot = "None";
    var CurrentSlot2 = "None";
    var ItemId = "None";
    var StoreMode: Boolean = false;
    var ItemSellPrice = 0;
    var ItemName = "";
    var totalChildren = 0;
    /////  Dynamic Variables  /////
    var container: MovieClip = new MovieClip;
    var btnUse: MenuItem = new MenuItem;
    var btnToss: MenuItem = new MenuItem;
    var btnClose: MenuItem = new MenuItem;



    public function Inventory() {
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ItemSlotClick);
    }


    public function InventoryFullCheck() {
        if (Slot1[0] != "empty" && Slot2[0] != "empty" && Slot3[0] != "empty" && Slot4[0] != "empty" && Slot5[0] != "empty" && Slot6[0] != "empty" && Slot7[0] != "empty" && Slot8[0] != "empty" && Slot9[0] != "empty" && Slot10[0] != "empty" && Slot11[0] != "empty" && Slot12[0] != "empty" && Slot13[0] != "empty" && Slot14[0] != "empty" && Slot15[0] != "empty") {
            InventoryFull = true;
        } else {
            InventoryFull = false;
        }
    }


    public function claimClick(e: MouseEvent): void {
        addToslot(Hammer);
    }



    public function addToslot(item) {
        if (Slot1[0] == "empty") {
            CurrentSlot = "itemSlot1";
            (item)();      <---------------------does hammer function at bottom
        } else if (Slot2[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot2.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot2[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot3[3] == "empty") {
            itemSlot3.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot3[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot4[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot4.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot4[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot5[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot5.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot5[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot6[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot6.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot6[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot7[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot7.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot7[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot8[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot8.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot8[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot9[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot9.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot9[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot10[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot10.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot10[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot11[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot11.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot11[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot12[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot12.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot12[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot13[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot13.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot13[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot14[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot14.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot14[0] = item;
        } else if (Slot15[0] == "empty") {
            itemSlot15.gotoAndStop(item);
            Slot15[0] = item;
        } else {
            InventoryFull = true;
        }
    }








    public function ClearVars(): void {
        ItemUse = "None";
        ItemId = "None";
        ItemSelected = "None";
        HideSelectBoxes();
    }






    public function Hammer(): void {
        trace(CurrentSlot);
        Object(root).InventoryMc.itemSlot1.gotoAndStop("Hammer");  <---can't get this to work...
    }



} //ends class
} //ends package
```

Comment: I see you don't really know how the site works, even though you asked several questions already, so welcome, and take the tour to understand how the site works: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I read it, but don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  If your talking about summing up the the question.  I want to know how to gotoAndStop within a class.  I provided the code in case it helps.

Comment: This is extremely unclear. Where are the itemSlot objects? If you have a class called InventoryMc and an object called InventoryMc, you're asking for trouble; give them different names, even if it's just inventoryMc

Comment: I had it as Inventory for the class name.  I just recently changed it, just to see if it would work.  Everything works fine except for the gotoAndStop("item").

Comment: consider `public var` and `public static` if you want to access those variables & movieclips from another class.